# p-calendar popup modal is not closing after choose date and time

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using `p-calendar` like below

```
<p-calendar showTime="showTime" placeholder="Start Date & Time" hourFormat="24" [minDate]="minDate" [defaultDate]="minDate" (click)="onPickDate()" formControlName="pick_up_datetime" [touchUI]="true"></p-calendar>
```

its working fine. This calendar displaying both `Date & Time` . Here my Question is on selecting Date and Time in the primeng  calendar  it should be hide when click on `button`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `primeng` in `node_modules` and open primeng->components->calendar and open calendar.js and add function

```
Calendar.prototype.onSetButton = function (clickedElement) {
        this.disableModality();
    };
```

and add a button in template (you can find template line around 1700 to 1710)

```
 <button id=\"set-button\" type=\"button\"  (click)=\"onSetButton(this)\">Set</button>
```

Hope it will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue if you are using showTime="true", remove the [showTime] and it perfectly works fine.